# Can't scoop out a twitter link from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get the link to a twitter account of a player. The problem is the twitter link is within an `iframe`. I can parse that using selenium. However, I would like to know if there is any alternative to parse the link using `requests` module making use of script tag or something.

[website link](https://247sports.com/Player/JT-Tuimoloau-46048440/)

If you scroll that site, you can see the twitter link located at the right sided area something like the image below:

[image]

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://247sports.com/Player/JT-Tuimoloau-46048440/"

def get_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    twitter = soup.select_one("a.customisable-highlight").get('href')
    print(twitter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to actually get the iframe, but maybe there is another way for you to fetch the Twitter name (and create a link to this Twitter account afterwards).

It seems like the information you need is hidden in a `div` tag with `class="tweets-comp"`. If you extract the value of the attribute `data-username`, you should end up with the name of the Twitter account:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://247sports.com/Player/JT-Tuimoloau-46048440/"

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

div = soup.find('div', {'class':'tweets-comp'})
print(div['data-username'])
# JT_tuimoloau
```

Comment: Glad I could help!